# How to edit a python(2.7) package from the command line in Linux machine. Note that I use python 3.9 in my machine

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, picamera

I couldn’t make changes in the file, how to edit this file and save it?!
[this is the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8Ysk.jpg)

[image: this is the command I used to open the python package]

Comment: Add more details. Any error traceback?

Comment: Hey Montaser, welcome to SO, please have a quick read of [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so we can better understand your issue with examples of code (in text, not an image)

Comment: Edit a source file has nothing to do with what version of Python it is part of — it's just a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using:

```
sudo nano # Filename here
```

Comment: Perfect answer !